# Centering text on a button in a WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple Windows Forms application with a `tabControl`. I have 3 panels on the `tabControl`, each having 5 buttons. The text on first set of buttons is hard-coded, but the next set populates when you click one from the first group, and then the same thing happens again for the last group when you click one of the buttons from the second group. In the [Design] view I manually set the `TextAlign` property of each button to `MiddleCenter`. However, when I run the application the text on the middle set of buttons is never centered. It is always `TopLeft` aligned. I've tried changing the font size and even explicitly setting the `TextAlign` property every time I set button text programmatically, as follows:

```
private void setButtons(List<string> labels, Button[] buttons)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i < labels.Count)
            {
                buttons[i].Text = labels.ElementAt(i);
                buttons[i].TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                buttons[i].Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                buttons[i].Text = "";
                buttons[i].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This image shows the result:
[image: alignment issue]

Does anyone have any ideas for what I'm missing?

Comment: post the code you use to change the text in the middle panel buttons

Comment: What is your problem then? the alignment of the middle row?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding your middle buttons to your button array buttons?

Comment: @FelicePollano - That is the code I use to set the text for them. It's the same code for the middle and the right button set. `labels` comes from a simple linq to sql query based on the text of the previous button.

Comment: @BartTeunissen Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: @MichaelEakins Yes, I'm sure. I put them all in their respective arrays int the constructor, and then I call setButtons on a particular button array depending on which button was clicked.

Comment: try check the length of `Text` of `Labels`

Comment: @spajce I started to say "As you can see from the image, the labels are shorter in the middle than on the left." However, it occurred to me that maybe they were different in the SQL table, and upon checking I realized that for some reason the strings in the middle column are actually nchar(50), not nvarchars, which explains the problem.

I added `.Trim()` to the `Text` assignment and it looks great now. Thanks!

Comment: yes ..welcome, i realized that my answer is wrong, i thought that you want to center the buttons from `panels` :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trim text which you are assign to button. Also you can refer label by index, without calling `ElementAt`

```
private void setButtons(List<string> labels, Button[] buttons)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count(); i++)
    {
        Button button = buttons[i];

        if (i < labels.Count)
        {
            button.Text = labels[i].Trim(); // trim text here
            // button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            button.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button.Text = "";
            button.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion about trimming just as you answered (after I looked at the SQL table), but you had it right on. Also, thanks for the tip on referencing items from a `List<T>`.

Comment: @WestonOdom yep, had same problems with alignment. Also get current button once - thus you will avoid retrieving it by index before assigning each property. And you can remove alignment setting (you did it in designer)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the UseCompatibleTextRendering property to true, then use the TextAlign property.

Answer (score 0):

The strings in the SQL table that were assigned to the middle column were actually `nchar(50)`, not `nvarchar(50)`, which explains the problem. I added .Trim() to the Text assignment and it looks great now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **TextAlign** from the **Properties** Menu and set it to **MiddleCenter** ...

If this does not work then the text you have for your button is larger than the actual button itself... to which you should either rescale your **Font Size** to a lower base size or a percent size of the actual button by using

```
btnFunction.Font = new Font(btnFunction.Font.Name, Convert.ToInt32(btnFunction.Height * 0.3333333333333333));
```

This would cause the button's font to be one third of the height of the button....